# Lower $ L^{1} $ bound for the Dirichlet kernel: $ \frac{1}{2\pi}\int _0^{2\pi} \left| \frac{\sin((N+1/2)x)}{\sin(x/2)}\right| dx \geq C \log N $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

I want to bound the $ L^{1} $ norm of the Dirichlet kernel from below. It is well known that 
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int _0^{2\pi} \left| \frac{\sin((N+1/2)x)}{\sin(x/2)}\right| dx \geq C \log N
$$ 
for some $C>0$ .

But some steps in the calculation are not clear:

1) $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2\pi}\int _0^{2\pi} \left|\frac{\sin((N+1/2)x)}{\sin(x/2)}\right| dx = \frac{1}{\pi}\int _0^{\pi} \left| \frac{\sin((N+1/2)x)}{\sin(x/2)}\right| dx$

2) $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\pi}\int _0^{\pi} \frac{\vert \sin((N+1/2)x)\vert}{\vert \sin(x/2)\vert} dx \geq \frac{1}{\pi}\int _0^{\pi} \frac{\vert \sin((N+1/2)x)\vert}{x} dx$

Are these steps right? Why are they true?

Comment: For 2) you mean $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\pi}\int _0^{\pi} \frac{\vert \sin((N+1/2)x)\vert}{\vert \sin(x/2)\vert} dx \geq \frac{1}{\pi}\int _0^{\pi} \frac{\vert \sin((N+1/2)x)\vert}{x/2} dx$

Answer (score 1):

1. This is due to the symmetry of the sine function. By periodicity the integral can be done on $[-\pi,\pi]$, and the integrand is an even function.
2. This is because $\sin x\le x$, $0\le x\le\pi$.

Comment: "by periodicty" is unclear : we are considering the $L^1([-\pi,\pi])$ norm here

Comment: If you like it better, because of the symmetries of the sine function, $\int_0^{2\pi}=2\int_0^\pi$.

Comment: Yes I meant $f(x)$ is $2\pi$ periodic so we look at its $L^1([0,2\pi])$ norm, and by even-ness $\|f\|_{L^1([0,2\pi]) }= 2\|f\|_{L^1([0,\pi]) }$